# git diff - appears no change, but shows changes

Tags: git, git-diff

I was messing around and saw something odd. I think this started when I recently enabled strip whitespace in my IDE. When I do a `git diff`, I'm now getting something like this:

```
@@ -106,8 +106,8 @@ dashboard.run(function($rootScope) {
             learnedOfFrom: 'sum'
         },
         {
-            docID: 1011, 
-            fullName: 'Lorem', 
+            docID: 1011,
+            fullName: 'Lorem',
```

I'm betting the "-" lines had a space at the end, that would normally show as a red block, and my IDE stripped them out on save, but for some reason that's not showing. Has anyone else run into this? I thought it was odd. This is the first time I've run across seeing "-" and "+" where the code looks identical and if it was trailing spaces getting stripped then I'm surprised `git diff` isn't showing big red blocks like usual.

Comment: If you're using vim, `:set list` to see whitespace and other invisible characters.

Comment: I'm just using the built-in `git diff` from the bash prompt, however, I was wondering about that the other day since I use vim more and more. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at that diff closely, and check for whitespace, you can see that the removed lines have a trailing space, and the added lines no longer do that.

So the change is basically that trailing whitespace is removed.

This would be the diff with spaces replaced by `·` for visibility:

```
-············docID:·1011,·
-············fullName:·'Lorem',·
+············docID:·1011,
+············fullName:·'Lorem',
```

Comment: I double-checked the paste. You're right. It is the stripped white space, but it's just not showing them as red. Thanks. :)